# cloud storage ACL based on Google user accounts

Tags: google-cloud-storage

- Add a Google user to a resource as owner
- Try to access resource through https://storage.googleapis.com/example.bucket.com/test.html link
- Returns: Anonymous callers do not have storage.objects.get access to object

Isn't this the point of the Google user based ACL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URL you are trying to access, `storage.googleapis.com`, is the XML API. See the [Request Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques?hl=en#endpoints) documentation for details.

Essentially, you get that error because that endpoint uses OAuth for authentication. Instead, you should use the *Authenticated Browser Downloads* endpoint, which authenticates based on the user's logged-in cookie.

In your case, the following URL would work:
https://storage.cloud.google.com/example.bucket.com/test.html